# Complete sequence in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem implies that $
\left\{x^{k}\right\}_{k \geq 0}
$ is complete in $L^2[0,1]$, I'm wondering if $
\left\{x^{2 k}\right\}_{k \geq 0}
$ still complete. Is there a proof that shows that this sequence is also complete?

Comment: @copper.hat: It's the difference of the two first elements of the sequence.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: I am aware of that, but that is not what is stated.

Comment: Does Stone-Weierstrass apply again?

Comment: The  term  complet is related to a normed vector space not to a sequence.

Comment: @DavidPeterson: How does that apply here? The span of $e_n(x) =  e^{i2 \pi nx}$ is dense in $L^2$ but the span of $e_{2k}$ is not.

Comment: @copper.hat It is usually defined that a sequence is complete if its span is dense.

Comment: @WillM.: Thanks. My  memory is fading. A set $A$ in a Hilbert space is complete **iff** $\langle a, x \rangle = 0$ for all $a \in A$ implies $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $f$ and $\epsilon>0$  and let $g(x) = f(\sqrt{x})$. Find a polynomial $p$ such that $\|g-p\|_\infty < \epsilon$. Then
$\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)-p(x^2)| < \epsilon$.

Hence the span of the functions $x \mapsto x^{2k}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ and hence in $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ can be approximated uniformly (hence also in $L^{2}$ norm) by polynomials in $x^{2}$ by Stone - Weierstrass  Theorem. Hence the given family is complete.